# InteractiveAssemblyLoader don't working in console app

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to use Roslyn script API in my project. I've created test console application and trying to resolve referencies using `InteractiveAssemblyLoader`

There is a code:

```
var scriptText = @"
    using System;
    using Test.Namespace.From.Referenced.Dll;

    var y = new TestType();
    var x = y.GetStringDescription();

    return x;
";

using (var interactiveLoader = new InteractiveAssemblyLoader())
{
    interactiveLoader.RegisterDependency(typeof(TestType).Assembly);

    var script = CSharpScript.Create<string>(
        scriptText,
        globalsType: typeof(Globals),
        options: ScriptOptions.Default,
        assemblyLoader: interactiveLoader
    );

    script.Compile();

    // exception raised here
    var result = await script.RunAsync(globals);
}
```

This code failed with exception

> 'The type or namespace name 'TEST' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)System.Exception
>   {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException}'

Windows console app, .NET 4.7.1.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Update. Since in comments we figured out you are trying to reference in-memory assembly, try this approach:

```
byte[] assemblyBytes = DownloadAssembly();
using (var interactiveLoader = new InteractiveAssemblyLoader()) {
    interactiveLoader.RegisterDependency(Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes));
    var script = CSharpScript.Create<string>(
        scriptText,
        globalsType: typeof(Globals),
        options: ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(new MemoryStream(assemblyBytes))),
        assemblyLoader: interactiveLoader
    );

    script.Compile();
    var result = await script.RunAsync(globals);
}
```

Comment: Not so easy. I'm trying to resolve in-memory library. That's the way how plugin system works in my app. Libraries with plugins downloads from server and load in memory. And I trying to add reference to this library in script. According this article https://www.strathweb.com/2016/03/roslyn-scripting-on-coreclr-net-cli-and-dnx-and-in-memory-assemblies/  it should  works, but it don't. Maybe I misunderstanding something.

Comment: So you have in-memory library. Why you cannot add it to references (via `AddReferences`)? Your link doesn't work for me by the way.

Comment: Roslyn need to read library from disk to load. You can't add to reference dll without Location.  AddReferences will raise exception.

Comment: @AlexeyNikiforov please check if updated answer helps with your situation.